# jQuery show and hide image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a new at this so go easy on me! Below I have some code which previews an image once it has been selected. However when no image is selected it comes up with this horrible box that has the default image symbol when no image is selected.

How can I make the image tag hide when nothing is selected and shown when something is?

HTML

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#"  width="400" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();            
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }            
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: Use a statement like: if `(image.src = null) { $('#blah').hide() } else $('#blah').show();`

Comment: @progo `image.src = null` there must be `== or ===` right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
var src = $('#blah').attr('src');
if(src==="#"){
$('#blah').css('display','none');
}
```

and add

```
$('#blah').css('display','inline');
```

to your function `readURL` so every time you upload an image to show again the `<img>` element

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tWqKf/)

Comment: FYI `<img>` elements are `inline` elements by default, not `block`.

Answer (score 0):

To Hide ([.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)):

```
$('#blah').fadeIn();
```

To Show ([.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)):

```
$('#blah').fadeOut();
```

**Note**: .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() provide nice animation to show/hide element.

Answer (score 0):

*Well since no one else gave something creative, I guess it's up to me.*

**Injecting a new image as it becomes available:**

```
....
reader.onload = function(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event,
        $newImg = $('<img/>').after('#imgInp');
    $newImg
        .attr({id: 'blah', alt: 'your image', src: e.target.result})
        .width(400);
};
....
```

**Also need to do error checking in case they deselect files:**

```
$('#imgInp').change(function() {
    if (this.files.length > 0 && $('#blah').is(':visible')) {
        $('#blah').remove();
    } else {
        readURL(this);
    }
});
```

## I like complicating things. It's fun.